# update database table from csv file remotely

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been asked by a client of mine if it would be possible for their warehouse to send a csv file of their stock to our server which then updates our sql server database automatically with the csv content. Aparently their sage system does this but im not sure if i can do it with standard sql server management studio 2008 i have on my server?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that I use to do such tasks:-

1. Build an SSIS package to open/parse/import the data.
2. Use the OPENROWSET function. If the filename of the CSV is always the same, then it makes this option simpler.